Mocked console.error inside setTimeOut not being called
I'm mocking the console.error function to test if it's being called, the test works to the point that it errors where it should and covers the correct part of the code, however, the test fails when I assert that the console error should have been called.
I've done this before and it worked, but it's the first time within a setTimeOut, which I think might be throwing it out in some way.
Actual code:
All code is covered
   debounceTimeout = setTimeout(async () => {
      if (sessionId) {
        try {
          const res = await fetch(
            `${appConfig.url.BASE_URL}/${GET_SET_DATA_API}/category-set-data`,
            {
              method: "POST",
              credentials: "include",
              headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                Cookie: `sessionId=${sessionId}`,
              },
              body: JSON.stringify({ state }),
            }
          );

          if (!res.ok) {
            // logs correctly
            console.error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
            throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${res.status}`);
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(`There was an error: ${error}`);
        }
      }
    }, delayTime);

Test:
describe("persist store", () => {
  let store: any;
  let state: RootState;

  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.clearAllMocks();
    store = makeStore();
    state = store.getState();
    global.fetch = jest.fn();
    jest.spyOn(global.console, "error").mockImplementation(() => {});
        jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    jest.spyOn(global.console, "error").mockRestore();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

 it("should throw error if state cannot be stored in", async () => {
    const sessionId = cookieMock.body.sessionId;
    jest.spyOn(global, "setTimeout").mockReturnValueOnce;

    (global.fetch as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce({
      ok: false,
      status: 500,
      statusText: "Session ID is required",
     });

     store.dispatch(setSessionId(sessionId));
     jest.runAllTimers();

     expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    // console.log("console.error", jest.spyOn(console, "error").mock);
    // expect(jest.spyOn(console, "error")).toHaveBeenCalled(); fails
 
 });
});

Below is a repo that can be used to run and view the issue in more detail:
https://github.com/royadams72/jest-test-issue
I updated the code again; I also found that if I removed the assertion for the console.error, the error would appear in my terminal, but the mock for the console should have suppressed it, once I put it in the before function the errors are suppressed as they should be, but I still cannot assert if console.error called

What's setSessionId? Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

I doubt calling repetively spyOn will return the same instance.
Can you put the mockInstace from brefore each jest.spyOn(global.console, "error").mockImplementation(() => {}); in a describe scope variable then use this instance in your assertion ?
describe("persist store", () => {
  let store: any;
  let state: RootState;
  let consoleErrorSpy: MockInstance;
  beforeEach(() => {
     jest.clearAllMocks();
     store = makeStore();
     state = store.getState();
     global.fetch = jest.fn();
     consoleErrorSpy = jest.spyOn(global.console, "error").mockImplementation(() => {});
     jest.useFakeTimers();
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    consoleErrorSpy.mockRestore();
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });

 it("should throw error if state cannot be stored in", async () => {
    const sessionId = cookieMock.body.sessionId;
    jest.spyOn(global, "setTimeout").mockReturnValueOnce;

    (global.fetch as jest.Mock).mockResolvedValueOnce({
      ok: false,
      status: 500,
      statusText: "Session ID is required",
     });

     store.dispatch(setSessionId(sessionId));
     jest.runAllTimers();

     expect(setTimeout).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
     console.log("console.error", consoleErrorSpy.mock);
     expect(consoleErrorSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();

 });

});

in my original code, I call  jest.useFakeTimers(); outside the describe, at the moment it's being called inside the before each, as it is in the repo. I'm getting coverage for that part of the code, which means it does work, and timers are started

ok. What happens if you call runAllTimers multiple time? or jest.advanceTimersByTime(100); multiple times? Nowadays I tend to avoid using fake timers because of problems like this...

Thanks for your suggestion. but it still doesn't register the console.error

I'm doing this at the moment; I'm just not putting the console.error into a variable, and it still fails if I assert the the error should be called

how can you assert it has been called without putting it in a variable first (before triggering the setTimeout)?
everytime you call spyOn you will get a different mockInstance (which has not been called)...

expect(jest.spyOn(console, "error")).toHaveBeenCalled()
I've tried it both ways previously, I've put it into a variable within the actual test itself and put into a variable outside the test, I did try your solution, but it did not work and I would have been surprised if it had, when I had tried it previously

in any case this: expect(jest.spyOn(console, "error")).toHaveBeenCalled() will ALLWAYS fail because it is a new MockInstance that cannot possibly been called
